# Cookie doesn't persist

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I've got an issue with my cookies. I'm authenticating users through LDAP and as long as the browser remains open users don't have to log back into the tool. They can even close the tab that's fine so long as the browser is open.

But the cookie gets removed the moment the user closes the browser. I've searched google a lot for this and I can't get any of the solutions to work such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102241/authentication-session-cookie-deleting-after-browser-close) or [that one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swathis/archive/2009/04/03/form-authentication-issue-remember-me-does-not-work-user-profile-roles-are-not-saved.aspx) for example.

Here's my setup once they authenticate on my logon page:

```
String encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

//Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

//Add expiration date to the cookie
authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

//Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

//You can redirect now.
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text, false);
```

My Web.Config looks like this:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" timeout="43200" name="adAuthCookie" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>`

Whatever I do the ASP.NET_SessionId and adAuthCookie cookies are always set to expire "When I close my browser". 
I want to avoid my users to always have to login when they close their browser and instead just do it once a month.

Comment: What does your `authTicket` look like and what Membership Provider are you using?

Comment: the authTicket looks normal, CookiePath to "/", Expired false, IsPersistent true etc... The only odd thing I can see is the Expiration date is set to 1h later although. As for the Membership Provider I'm still new to this but I do not believe I'm using one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set a machineKey in your web.config.
If one is not specified either there or machine.config, it will be generated on start up and reset everytime the website is restarted, invalidating the encryption in the cookie.

[machineKey element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help. I added: `<machineKey decryption="Auto" validation="AES"
                validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"
                decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />` I also tried to add manual keys which didn't work.

Comment: I generate mine here [http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) make sure you got the format correct. That exhausts my ideas for now though.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still no luck. I added `protection="All"` to the forms part of the WebConfig as well but that made no difference. The cookies' expiration date is still set to "when browser close".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure browser is not set to delete cookies on close. There is such paranoid setting somewher in security options (I think in IE it is Advanced -> Security ->Empty temporary folders...)

Use Fiddler or other tool to make sure you send cookies with correct expiration to the browser. This way you verify where error is server or client side.

Comment: The browsers are not set to delete cookies on close. As for the expiration I can see that actually the ASP.NET_SessionId has the correct expiration date set to a month later. The adAuthCookie however doesn't for some reason.

Comment: "The adAuthCookie however doesn't for some reason" sounds like the explanation of the behavior you see. It is strange - code that sets cookie expiration on authCookie looks ok. Are you sure this is the only code that adds this cookie?

Comment: Sorry I took this long to respond. Yes this is the only code that affects this cookie. I'm still having the problem with this :/

Comment: I don't know - your snippet of code looks ok. One more random guess - when you look in Fiddler is there only one "adAuthCookie" in respons with set-cookie headers?