# ASP.net MVC 4 session cookie expires when user closes browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, lifetime

I had the same issue like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102241/authentication-session-cookie-deleting-after-browser-close). Because I am lucky, his solution also worked for me.
But I think it's a bit dirty and I was wondering if there isn't a better one.

I've set up this configuration on IIS, but the cookies will always expire when the user closes her browser (if I don't use he "cookie hack")

[image: an image showing my IIS configuration]

**Any Ideas?**

**EDIT:** To clearify: It not the Server side session that is lost, it's only the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie lifetime, which is incorrect.

**EDIT2:** After some Research, I was wondering when the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie is actually set. If I delete it (using Firefox) and refreshing the page (even several times) a new one won't appear ... What's going on here?

**EDIT3:** I just found out, that the session id cookie will be set if I put something into the session, so that question (EDIT2) is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session cookie will exire as soon as possible for security reasons. One should not extent it's lifetime due to [session hijacking](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Hijacking).

If you need "the old session back", then use ASP.NET authentication and generate a new session after the users comes back to the site. This will safe memory and also increase overall security.